# how to detect the similar unordered sequences?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, sequence

I want to find the similar intersections in a road network. My trick is to find the most similar sequence of names of streets. I have created several lists of names. one of them is the reference and the two others are corresponding ones. I want to find the one which has the same street names and same number of occurrence.

it is necessary to know that the order of name should not matter but only the number of occurrence of the similar names matters.

example:

reference name sequence:
`[u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan']`

corresponding name sequence of neighbors are :
    `{91: [u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan'], 142: [u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u' ']}`

first, I need to know if for this problem there is already a solution. second, choosing the list as a container of sequences is a good idea? and finally, if so, how to solve it?

I was think of regular expression but seems no useful as the order is not fix.

Comment: I am wondering what this quick down-vote is for?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a map of the occurrence of each key and then subtract the occurrence once you check the reference array, then you can make sure you're getting the correct answer, even if the array is out of order in the map

```
reference = [u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan']
sequence = {91: [u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan'], 142: [u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u' ']}
def getMatching(reference, sequence):
    for value in sequence.values():
        tempMap = {}
        for v in value:
            try:
                tempMap[v] += 1
            except KeyError:
                tempMap[v] = 1

        # tempMap now contains a map of the each element in the array and their occurance in the array
        for v in reference:
            try:
                # Everytime we find this reference in the 'reference' list, subtract one from the occurance
                tempMap[v] -= 1
            except:
                pass

        # Loop through each value in the map, and make sure the occurrence is 0
        for v in tempMap.values():
            if v != 0:
                break
        else:
            # This else statement is for the for loop, if the else fires, then all the values were 0
            return value
        continue
    return None

print getMatching(reference, sequence) # Prints [u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan']
```

Now if you have this instead, it will still work:

```
reference = [u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Barytongatan']
sequence = {142: [u'Tunnlandsgatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan', u' '], 91: [u'Barytongatan', u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan']}
print getMatching(reference, sequence) # Prints [u'Barytongatan', u'Barytongatan', u'Tunnlandsgatan'] even though they are not in the same order as reference
```

Comment: here is the point that the order in the lists may not be the same, so equality of the values in the dictionary with the reference will not be the answer.